# Custom project visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to create a project in Visual studio 2017 that:

1. I can write html / jss / css only in the front end (can still be aspx extension)
2. Have the visual design mode available
3. Create a separate web service for the server side c# connectivity.

I want to create a javascript html css only front end (but I like VS IDE).
all back end stuff will just be web services and front end ajax where needed.

ps how does this approach sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the use of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is the open source, cross-platform version of Visual Studio. It comes with Intellisense, the colour theme and a solution explorer. It had less of the features, as it is more of an editor than an IDE.

The only thing this application doesn't have is the visual design mode, but the autocomplete functions will help you out there! :D

Visual Studio wasn't really developed for pure client-side web development, so I would suggest using Code, over Community!

As for your approach, if you wanted to spread your wings a little and perhaps expand your sphere of skills, I'd totally recommend using [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?tabs=aspnetcore2x). It is the latest roll out of the ASP.NET family and contains support for C# inline with HTML as well as data controlling with C# classes.

I hope this has helped you with your project! :)